# How to tell WCF client to read settings out of different config file?

Tags: .net, wcf, configuration-files

I'm building a component that is an extension for another software product. It's loaded as a dll into that product, and therefore I don't have control over the main exe's app.config file. My component uses WCF and I'd like to be able to configure it using a .config file instead of programmatically within the code. Is there a way to tell WCF to get all the binding etc settings from a specific config file?

Comment: In brief: no. WCF uses .NET standard config system, and that config system doesn't support separate / custom / class-library level config's

Comment: You can use a xml-file that looks like a config, but actually is just a text file that is compiled as a Resource. But there is a problem:  you will have to parse values and create service in code. So it's no better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately @marc_s's answer was the one I went with: no. Instead we store configuration options with other system settings and then apply them programmatically to the binding etc settings at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

The .NET config file mechanism is scoped by AppDomain, so in principle you could achieve this by creating a separate AppDomain to host your WCF stuff. It's quite a lot of work, though, as you would have to code the necessary cross-domain communication to expose your extension functionality to the host process.